# ASP.Net Controls in Delphi

Tags: asp.net, delphi, winapi

I'm sure this question has been asked already but I couldn't find any posts.

Is it possible to use an ASP.net control in Delphi 2006 for Win32?  We have some Dev Express ASP.Net visual controls (Chart controls to be exact) that we would like to use in our Delphi application.

Is this possible and how could it be done, preferably without the need to purchase more third party components.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you cannot use this kind of controls directly in a Delphi Win32 Application, because this components are designed to run in a web server with ASP and expose the results  to a browser client, i think which your best option is use a local (or remote) web server and make a web page which accepts HTTP requests, and then in `TWebBrowser` in your Delphi Win32 app load the page to get results.

Answer (score 2):

That is not going to be possible as the DevExpress ASP.NET controls are wired up via handlers in the web.config and not something that can be forced into Delphi. I assume you have looked at DevExpress's VCL controls for ([Delphi and C++ Builder Controls](http://devexpress.com/Products/VCL/index.xml)) on it's website? If the VCL product suite does not have what you need then you will need to look elsewhere.